# Enabling debug draw on CCPhysicsNode causes crash

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, physics, spritebuilder

Versions: Cocos2D V3.4, Xcode 7.2.1, SpriteBuilder 1.4.9.

You can download my project [here](https://github.com/ud230688/SpaceShooter.spritebuilder.git). It was created with SpriteBuilder.

Enabling debug draw on CCPhysicsNode causes a crash:

```
CCPhysicsNode *_physicsWorld;


_physicsWorld = [CCPhysicsNode node];
_physicsWorld.gravity = ccp(0,0);
_physicsWorld.debugDraw = YES;//if debugDraw set to NO, crash will not occur, it happens only when its set to YES
_physicsWorld.collisionDelegate = self;
[_scene addChild:_physicsWorld];
```

Error:

> Assertion failure in -[CCRenderStateGL
>   initWithBlendMode:shader:shaderUniforms:copyUniforms:]

My code to add physics body to the CCSprite:

```
  _PlayerSprite.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, _PlayerSprite.contentSize} cornerRadius:0]; // 1 

  _PlayerSprite.physicsBody.collisionGroup = @"playerGroup"; // 2

  [_PhysicsWorld addChild:lobjPlayerSprite
                        z:Z_ORDER_PLAYERS];
```

Then code crashes at `CCRendererBasicTypes initWithBlendMode`:

```
-(instancetype)initWithBlendMode:(CCBlendMode *)blendMode shader:(CCShader *)shader shaderUniforms:(NSDictionary *)shaderUniforms copyUniforms:(BOOL)copyUniforms

crashes here:-
NSAssert(shader, @"CCRenderState: Shader is nil");
```

Comment: please explain the reason why its happening

Comment: edit the title of your question. It really freaks me out.

Comment: that means its working for u..shall i share my code with u....so u can have better overview

Comment: Ok. do share but only the relevant part of code which you think is having error.

Comment: here is the link of the project :- https://github.com/ud230688/SpaceShooter.spritebuilder       here are the relevant function name which code concerns :- [VisualWorld addPlayer]  and [GamePlayScene initWithVisualWorld:(VisualWorld*)lobjVW
                resources:(NSArray*)larrayResources].....Please check and lemme know if you have any problem or query regarding code in project. @psyco

Comment: hi, hope u able to download and check the code...- @psyco

Answer (score 1):

Your project was created with SpriteBuilder which has not been updated since April 2015. The version of Cocos2D that SpriteBuilder ships with was released before Xcode 7 and does not include a few necessary fixes for Xcode 7 and iOS 9. You can read more about this [here](http://forum.cocos2d-spritebuilder.org/t/tutorial-spritebuilder-1-4-9-working-with-xcode7/17946).

To fix this, you need to manually update Cocos2D. Follow the steps on the previous link or use [this](https://www.makeschool.com/tutorials/update-cocos2d-for-xcode-7-and-ios-9) as a reference (it's more visual).